# NetBeans GUI designer window to change between design and source not showing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, matisse

Right now I am working on a GUI application In java using the GUI builder that comes with NetBeans.

However I have found some kind of strange bug/feature, as I am no longer able to see the window that allows users to change between "source" and "design" (Design is the drag and drop NetBeans gui builder while source is the code where you can add your own methods and so forth).

NOTE: the red is censored information that is not necessary.

[image: A screenshot of my GUI application where i highlight where the window should be. The red is censored information that is irrelevant like the logo and some text etc.]

When I right click on a component to add event code, then it takes me to the source (without a window for me to change back to design, it goes back to design when i close and reopen it). So I know that NetBeans recognizes that this is indeed a `JFrame` form with the NetBeans GUI designer, and the source code is indeed availible..

I could not find any answers to this question on this site or on the web, I have tried resetting the windows but it did not work, I also couldn't find the window when I clicked on the window option. I am sure there is some easy question but I am unable to find it. Please forgive me if this was an easy question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the menu bar, try clicking View -> Show Editor Toolbar

Comment: OH well i suppose this was a very easy quesetion...Nonetheless thansk a bunch for your answer : ) We all start out like noobs in the beginning : )